# How to convert the string of double quotes appended with backslash in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

For example

```
"{"$type":"Equal","value":
 {"$type":"UserField","value":"country"},"compareValues":
 [{"$type":"Literal","value":"INDIA"}],"joinvalues":
 [{"$type":"Literal","value":null}]}"
```

to

```
 "{\"$type\":\"Equal\",\"value\":
  {\"$type\":\"UserField\",\"value\":\"country\"},\"compareValues\":
  [{\"$type\":\"Literal\",\"value\":\"INDIA\"}],\"joinvalues\":
  [{\"$type\":\"Literal\",\"value\":null}]}"
```

Comment: Use single quotes `'` around your object string

Comment: Or please share why you need this ?

Comment: Why is your object string inside `""` ? It should be inside `'`. Also, you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert object into string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = {"$type":"Equal","value":
 {"$type":"UserField","value":"country"},"compareValues":
 [{"$type":"Literal","value":"INDIA"}],"joinvalues":
 [{"$type":"Literal","value":null}]}


JSON.stringify(json).replace(/\"/g, "\\\"");
```